# Write first and second column rows in listview inside each row in a text file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, text-files

I'm using `WinForms`. In my form I have a `listview` and a button. When I click on the button the program writes all of the items in the `listview` into a text file. The problem is that I want the first and second column to be in one line.

Here is my code so far that i use to write to the text file:

```
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(DirectoryPath))
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(item.Text);
                    for (int i = 1; i < item.SubItems.Count; i++)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(item.SubItems[i].Text);
                    }
                }
             }
```

**My ListView**

[image: My list View]

**Problem output text file**

[image: Problem Text file]

**How I want the text file to display**

[image: Goal]

Comment: You could just use sw.Write(Item.Text) instead of WriteLine, so the line is not terminated after the Item's text is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just

```
       using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(DirectoryPath))
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                sw.Write(item.Text + ": ");
                for (int i = 1; i < item.SubItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(item.SubItems[i].Text);
                }
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your first cell "FirstPage" is the parent and all other items are sub items. Assuming you have only two columns below answer will work.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(DirectoryPath))
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {

                sw.Write(string.Format("{0} :",item.Text));
                for (int i = 1; i < item.SubItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        sw.Write(string.Format("{0} :",item.SubItems[i].Text));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(item.SubItems[i].Text);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

- Alternative is; add each new row as a new item to the list view

  ```
      string[] row = { "FirstPage", "$1.00" };
      string[] row2 = { "SecondPage", "$1.00" };

      var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
      listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
      var listViewItem2 = new ListViewItem(row2);
      listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem2);
  ```

  and so on. You can iterate through a foreach loop for this adding and then use the below code which is flexible.

  ```
     using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(DirectoryPath))
      {
          foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
          {

              sw.Write(string.Format("{0} :",item.Text));
              for (int i = 1; i < item.SubItems.Count; i++)
              {
                  sw.WriteLine(item.SubItems[i].Text);
              }
          }
      }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a more elegant way:

```
var str = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                   .Select(x => x.SubItems.Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>())
                   .Select(x => string.Join(":", x.Select(s => s.Text)));
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"d:\file.txt", str);
```

**Note:** If you want to limit the columns for example save only first two columns, you can select sub items at second line this way: `x.SubItems.Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>().Take(2)`

Comment: I love LINQ, but there are times, like this, when the main thing it does is obscure what the code is doing.

Comment: @AgapwIesu The code works this way: `Cast<T>()` Converts an enumerable collection to a `IEnumerable<T>` So we can use linq methods on it. So we get list of items in first line. Then in second line we selected all sub items of an item so the result is a list which each element contains a list of sub items of an item. Then in third line we selected text from all sub items and using `string.Join`, joined those sub items using ":" as delimiter.

Comment: @AgapwIesu Practice makes perfect. When you use it enough, you will read lines as simple as you read a for loop and you learn to parse it and you will see it's one of the best solutions which you can use for such case.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate the List View items, concatenate each one of the sub items into each other and then add the concatenated string to the text file at the end... I have adapted your code:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(DirectoryPath))
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
    {

        string strText = "";

        //I'm not sure why you start at 1 and not 0, anyway:
        for (int i = 1; i < item.SubItems.Count; i++)
        {
            strText+= " " + item.SubItems[i].Text;
        }

        sw.WriteLine(strText);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think the line in your code needs correction

    strText+= " " + sw.WriteLine(item.SubItems[i].Text);

should actually be

    strText+= " " + item.SubItems[i].Text;